# Why is there a limit on how many Triage questions I can review?

Tags: discussion, triage

After reviewing 20 questions in [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage), I get this message:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 Triage questions, come back in X hours to continue reviewing.

After looking around for a while, I found several questions about the 20 reviews limit, but none that explain why it exists.

Why is there a limit on how many Triage questions can be reviewed?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So questions would be reviewed faster.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The purpose of review is *community* review, not "three bored people review everything" review. If there were no limits, there'd be no reason to expect the latter wouldn't eventually happen.

Comment: And those bored people wouldn't get any work done in the office otherwise. SO looks out for people's employment. \s

Comment: I would also assume it's so you don't get brain dead and start glossing over items.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good reason as well, and one that has inspired a lot of related limits also.